# Why if ping 0 is a ping to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I am curious to know, why if use the command `ping 0` is like pinging 127.0.0.1

```
shell:> ping 0                                                                                                                                                                            
PING 0 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, on Windows 10 pinging `0` causes `ping` to try `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Please see this Q&A on UNIX.se https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99336/48232